# how can track the payments in listener with id and also retrieve payments details from listener

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, chained-payments

My packet for the chained payment has the url to ipn-Listener.php, however I do not know how to track the payment (any sort of id? And how can access the id in the listener?). I have tested the listener with the ipn simulator everything works fine, but with my test payment I can’t get any information about the payments from listener. I have used the code provided by paypal for the listener. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When working with Adaptive Payments the URL you pass in the IPNNotificationURL parameter will only be used to send application specific details about the transaction.  Are you at least getting that?  If not, then you must not be including it in your request or you must have something wrong with the listener that isn't receiving those IPNs correctly.

A second IPN would be sent if you are both the app owner and the receiver of the payment (assuming you have IPN configured in your PayPal account profile.)  In that case you would get one IPN with app specific details based on the API request, and then you would get another IPN with more payment specific details based on the IPN profile setting.  These would both hit right around the same time.

The app specific IPN should contain the Pay Key, and then you could pass that into the [PaymentDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/) to get some more details, too.